# Why are the googletest targets getting installed by default when I install my project, and how can I prevent that from happening?

Tags: cmake

The googletest targets are getting installed when I run `cmake --install` (not my own test executable targets- the googletest targets). Why is this happening and how can I prevent them from getting installed by default?

I'm still trying to work out how to get google tests to build when I do

```
 cmake --build build
```

but not install when I do

```
 cmake --install build
```

If In the root CMakeList I have

```
 add_subdirectory(tests)
```

then the tests build - great. But they get installed when I do `cmake --install build`

if I have

```
 add_subdirectory(tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

(as per previous question [how to prevent cmake --install installing google test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844405/how-to-prevent-cmake-install-installing-google-test))

then the tests dont get built when I do `cmake --build build`

I have to go

```
 cmake --build build --target AllTests
```

but this didnt change anything, googletest still got installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the options documentation and registration for the GTest CMake options. Particularly the `INSTALL_GTEST` option. See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt. It is as follows:

```
option(INSTALL_GTEST "Enable installation of googletest. (Projects embedding googletest may want to turn this OFF.)" ON)
```

That part where it says "`ON`" is the argument that specifies the default value of the option if left unspecified by the user (see [the `option` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html)).

You want to set the option to [any falsy CMake constant (`OFF`, `NO`, `FALSE`, `0`, etc.)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#basic-expressions), which you can do in any of the ways you specify `option`s. You can do it on the commandline with [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) (`-DINSTALL_GTEST=OFF`), you can hardcode it for all users of your own project by [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html)ting it in your CMakeLists.txt file (`set(INSTALL_GTEST OFF)`), or you could set it in a [configuration preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) if you use CMake presets.

You can see where that option is used to do that installation here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/CMakeLists.txt